# Can't change the current cursor

Tags: c#, cursor, wait

The following code tests my Connection. The connection timeout is set to 30 seconds. I wanna Change the current Cursor to the waitcursor but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
private void pbConnectionTest_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
    try {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestConnection));
        thread.Start();
    } finally {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

I also tried to handle the Cursor in my function TestConnection. But it doens't work there ether.

This example works without Problems:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
try
{
  Thread.Sleep(5000);  // wait for a while
}
finally
{
  Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a winforms or wpf application?

Comment: Are you using Thread.Sleep() in the code which tests the connection or Timer, if Thread.Sleep(anyInteger); anyInteger is counted in milliseconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This following code is wrong(logically).

```
finally 
{             
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Here what happens is

1. Cursor will be changed to wait cursor.
2. Thread will be started and, immediately the Cursor will be changed again to default.(before thread is finished).

So you should place follwing statement after your thread is finished.

```
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

Here what you should know is, the call `thread.Start();` will immediately return.(does not wait for thread to finish)

**Solution1**
  Remove statement from `finally` block and do as follows.

```
void TestConnection()
{
    ..............
    ..................


   this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
   {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
   }));   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because your first example immmediately changes the cursor back to default.

Since you are starting a new thread, that thread will run the TestConnection code. The original thread continues its execution, where finally block changes the cursor back to the default. You need to wait until the thread completes before you change the cursor back - if you can do it at the end of the TestConnection method, that would be the easiest way to do it.

*But just because it is simplest, it might not be the right solution. You might want to separate concerns, separate UI from connection testing. In this case, you will need an event, callback or similar; to notify you when the connection testing  is done.*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there will be no pause in your example because it is just starting a thread and not waiting for the execution of that thread to come back.  But to force the cursor you can use `OverrideCursor` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor(v=vs.110).aspx , but like I said this probably wont do anything unless you wait for your thread to come back.

```
try 
{
    Mouse.Overidecursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestConnection));
    thread.Start();
} 
finally 
{
    Mouse.Overidecursor = null;
}
```

If you are going to wait for the tread to finish you could you a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and use the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event to change the cursor back to the default cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some time passed, and when I found myself in the same situation.
I solved it as follows:

> This.UseWaitCursor = true;